# Use OpenShift environment variable from nodejs

Tags: node.js, openshift

Its first time I am using OpenShift . But I dont find any document how to use nodejs to create a file in  OPENSHIFT_TMP_DIR . Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the following to use the OPENSHIFT_TMP_DIR in your node.js code.

```
process.env.OPENSHIFT_TMP_DIR
```

Just use that environment variable with your code that writes to a file as the location and you should be good.